# Browsersync apache server on existing proxy - stuck on loading

Tags: apache, proxy, virtualhost, browser-sync, gulp-browser-sync

I'm having a problem making my gulp with browsersync run. When i run **gulp sync** the browser runs blank page that is stuck on loading, on http://localhost:8080/app_dev.php url.

I use proxy option to virtual host that's linked to my local server with php app (symfony). Here's my configuration:

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'progress_app.localhost/app_dev.php',
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
});
```

**httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\progress_app\web"
 DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName progress_app.localhost
    ServerAlias progress_app.localhost

    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\progress_app\web>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you manage to find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same problem (gulp, apache, symfony 2, app_dev)

Comment: Same problem here. Did anyone solve this?